# Is this correct way to evaluate $\int_{-3}^3 d|x|$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> > Evaluate $$I=\int _{-3}^3 d|x|$$

What I did is, split the integral as follows by using the definition of $|x|$.

$$I=\int_{-3}^0 d(-x)+\int_0^3 dx=-\int_{-3}^0dx+\int_0^3dx=0$$

Any comments?

Comment: Out of curiosity what does $d\vert x\vert$ mean to you?

Comment: Look at wiki entry of [Riemann Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral), this is the sort of definition you need to define your integral rigorously.

Comment: In a similar fashion, by the chain rule $d|x|=\frac{d|x|}{dx}\,dx=\frac x{|x|}\,dx$. The same result follows.

Comment: @Aruralreader That's the usual notation for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Comment: Your calculations are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts of Riemann–Stieltjes integrals,
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}g(x)=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d}f(x),$$
gives in your case:
$$\int_a^b\mathrm d|x|=|b|-|a|.$$
See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539133).